# Is there a method for detecting CUDA OutOfMemory before train?

Tags: tensorflow, graph, deep-learning, out-of-memory, gpu

I train the Graph Neural Net.
Because the size of the input data changes every time, I met an unexpected OOM error.
I will try to prevent this error heuristically (node truncation).

How can I know the size of the graph on the CPU causes a CUDA OOM error when allocated to the GPU?

Thanks!

- TensorFlow 1
- RTX 3090

Comment: Can you post a bit of code to see what's your current approach?

Comment: If you are not using `Tensorflow 2.4` version, please upgrade it accordingly because it support your GPU card.